# What is fesm2015 and how it relates to esm2015?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I know that esm2015 refers to ecmascript modules described by the [ecmascript 2015 specification (modules section)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-modules)

In some libraries under `node_modules/` I see, next to the directory `esm2015/`, another one  called `fesm2015/`.

- **What is fesm2015**?
- Does it **extend esm2015**?
- Is there any **specification describing** it?

Comment: Per e.g. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview it's *flattened* (i.e. to a single file) ES module (i.e. using import/export syntax).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's part of the Angular Package Format.

> FESM - short for Flattened ES Modules and consists of a file format
> created by flattening all ES Modules accessible from an entry point
> into a single ES Module.

The specification appears to be in this google doc:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs

More info:

> We strongly recommend that you optimize the build artifacts before
> publishing your build artifacts to npm, by flattening the ES Modules.
> This significantly reduces the build time of Angular applications as
> well as download and parse time of the final application bundle.
> Please check out the excellent post "The cost of small modules" by
> Nolan Lawson.
>
> Angular compiler has support for generating index ES module files that
> can then be used to flattened module using tools like Rollup,
> resulting in a file format we call Flattened ES Module or FESM.
>
> FESM is a file format created by flattening all ES Modules accessible
> from an entry point into a single ES Module. It’s formed by following
> all imports from a package and copying that code into a single file
> while preserving all public ES exports and removing all private
> imports.
>
> The shortened name “FESM” (pronounced “phesom”) can have a number
> after it such as “FESM5” or “FESM2015”. The number refers to the
> language level of the JavaScript inside the module. So a FESM5 file
> would be ESM+ES5 (import/export statements and ES5 source code).
>
> To generate a flattened ES Module index file, use the following
> configuration options in your tsconfig.json file:

```
{   "compilerOptions": {
     ...
     "module": "es2015",
     "target": "es2015",
     ...   },   "angularCompilerOptions": {
     ...
     "flatModuleOutFile": "my-ui-lib.js",
     "flatModuleId": "my-ui-lib"   } }
```

> Once the index file (e.g. my-ui-lib.js) is generated by ngc, bundlers
> and optimizers like Rollup can be used to produce the flattened ESM
> file.